# Pandas throwing XLRDError when trying to read .xls file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-scraping, format

I'm working on building a script to automatically download an Excel file from our organization's dashboard and open it as a Pandas data frame. I've got the code working to download the file, but I've found that, while it's saved with a .xls extension, it's actually an HTML file.

Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("report.xls")
```

And I'm receiving this error:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Title\tCo'
```

I've tried using read_html, but that returns "No tables found". This makes sense, as there is no html to render. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a tab delimited file. The following works:

```
pd.read_table("report.xls")
```

You can then save the table as a .xlsx document and everything is good.